# Morse Theory and critical groups

Tags: algebraic-topology, morse-theory

Please I have a question:

What is the relation between Morse theory and critical point theory ?

I studied the Morse inequalities and critical groups, but i can not not find or at least i do not understand the results of Morse given by critical groups and Morse inequalities .

Please

Thank you .

Answer (score 1):

This Wikipedia [article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morse_theory) on Morse Theory describes what you are talking about fairly well.

Critical points are essential to Morse theory, because the topology of level sets changes at every critical point. The way it changes is encoded by the *index* of the critical point. Using all of the indices, one can compute an estimate on Betti numbers.

This may bit have answered your question; if it has not, please post more details, and I or someone else will help more.

Comment: Sorry, autocorrect. Did it get you too?

Comment: I wrote Betti but my iPad changed it to Bertie. It's hard in the iPad!

Answer (score 0):

The critical group (with values in $G$) of a non-degenerate critical point is precisely $G$ in degree $k$ where $k$ is the index of the critical point. I believe any resource discussing critical groups should mention this.